# Facebook's setReadPermissions() on Login Button deprecated - what to use instead?

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, facebook-login

Im following Facebook's login tutorial for Android SDK and it seems `login_button.setReadPermissions()` is now deprecated:

[image]

What do I use as a replacement?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

as written [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/current/facebook/com/facebook/login/widget/loginbutton.html/#setpermissions-javalangstring-) `setReadPermission` is deprecated, use **`setPermissions`** instead